# How can I add recipients to email created with Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow-activity

I have a List with a column called "Add Recipients", 
    Require that this column contains information: No
    Allow multiple selections: Yes
    Allow selection of: People and Groups
    Choose from: SharePoint Group ( members)
    Show field: User name

I have a simple workflw, with "Send a Message" Action; in the field TO there are some Sharepoint Users. In the CC field there is the "Workflow lookup", wirh the "source"=ADD RECIPIENTS column, show field User Name OR Email Addresses. In both cases when the ADD RECIPIEntS is empty, the workflow stops, with an error, and the email is not sent neither to the recipients that I wrote in the field TO. Instead I need that when the ADD RECIPIENTS is empty, the workflow sends email to the recipients in the field "TO", ignoring the fact that ADD RECIPIENTS IS empty. is it possible?
otherwise, if the ADD recipients contains at least one user/group, the workflow is ok

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a variable that contains the 2 hard coded users (semi-colon delimited) and has a reference to the lookup field. Use this variable in your To field on the email action.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to build the local variable of the workflow, and the first step of the workflow is SET THE VARIABLE and i choose "create string" and I build: hardcodedemail@..;[%ADD RECIPIENT%]? BUT when I create the VAriable, I can choose only STRING and not "EMAIL ADDRESS", so that whne I use the variable in the TO field, the email sending doesn't work

Comment: I mean you set a variable user1@my.com; user2@my.com; [lookup column] (as an email address). In your Email action, you do a Workflow Lookup for a User. In the modal, you select Workflow Variables and Parameters and select the variable from previous step.

Comment: it doesn't work. It seems that the system doesn't convert the string in email addresses, even if I set the look up filed "RETURN FIELD AS email address" may b

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

First off what SharePoint are you using?
With SharePoint 2010 and up you can do the following:

[image: Workflow]

You trigger the event in the workflow and then send a mail.

In the To set whoever.

in the CC you can use workflow lookup current item and choose add recipients witch I understand as a field in your list.
Your question is very hard to understand. Hope this helps.