# Send an email to an address I recovered from a web service

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, email

I am trying to send an email to an address retrived
by a custom `REST` service.

Having got the email address I set it to a variable myemailvariable

Now I would like to send an email to that address.

I have tried creating a message in the workflow and set the email as follows:

1. Workflow Lookup for a User
2. Workflow Parameters and Users
3. FieldFromSource = myemailvariable

but it fails on `SendEmail` with the following error:

```
SocialRESTExceptionProcessingHandler.DoServerExceptionProcessing - SharePoint Server Exception [System.InvalidOperationException: A recipient must be specified.    
 at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.SendEmail_Client(EmailProperties properties)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.Utilities.SPUtilityServerStub.InvokeStaticMethod(String methodName, ClientValueCollection xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeStaticMethodWithMonitoredScope(String methodName, ClientValueCollection args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPathRoot(Boolean mainRequestPath, EdmParserNode node, Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation& methodInfo)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPath(Boolean mainRequestPath, String path, String pathForErrorMessage)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()
```

Do you know how to send an email to an address retrieved by a custom REST service with workflows? I'd like to do it staying in `SharePoint Designer` (thus without writing code)

Comment: Have you check that your workflow is correctly getting your email address (ex: log in history the variable) ? I would also try to get the email address by hand then use the output to hardcode it in the Send an email action and see if if it's working correctly.

Comment: @JayHell I'm sure the email is correct as I also insert it in a list item. If I hardcode it, the email is sent correctly. But I see, in this case there is some kind of translation from email to user as I see in the email recipient in the workflow Name and Surname corresponding to that user. I think if you created a variable with an email and tried to send an email to that variable it would fail.

Comment: All "Return field as" output options fail ?

Comment: Could you tell me the step to turn a string into a user with "Return field as"?

Comment: Check the screenshot in this answer : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62787/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflowhow-to-send-email-to-multiple-users

Comment: +1 as it looked a good idea but it doesn't work. I see in the example they are fishing email out  of list item fields while I'm getting the email from  a rest service.I don't know it that's the reason

Comment: It seems this user has the same problem and emails are not converted in users... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57103/how-can-i-add-recipients-to-email-created-with-workflow